# Previous observations

Tags: foreach, stata, missing-data

I need your help with the following problem. 
My data is

```
ack            det                     uniquenr

02mar2015 10:30:19  27feb2015 17:03:25 1

09mar2015 11:56:44  07mar2015 22:05:52 2

16mar2015 09:59:51  09mar2015 11:08:36 2

16mar2015 09:59:51  09mar2015 11:08:36 2

16mar2015 09:59:51  09mar2015 11:08:36 2

16mar2015 09:59:51  09mar2015 11:08:36 2

24feb2015 15:03:00  21feb2015 10:23:00 3
```

`ack` and `det` are datetimes. `det` must be matched to the earliest possible following `ack` with the same unique number. As appears in the example above, `det` of 09mar2015 is wrong. I would like the result to be:

```
ack            det                     uniquenr

02mar2015 10:30:19  27feb2015 17:03:25 1

09mar2015 11:56:44  07mar2015 22:05:52 2

09mar2015 11:56:44  09mar2015 11:08:36 2

09mar2015 11:56:44  09mar2015 11:08:36 2

09mar2015 11:56:44  09mar2015 11:08:36 2

09mar2015 11:56:44  09mar2015 11:08:36 2

24feb2015 15:03:00  21feb2015 10:23:00 3
```

I have tried the following code:

```
sort uniquenr det
bysort uniquenr (det): gen v1= (ack[_n-1]-det)/(1000*60*60)
gen v2= (ack-det)/(1000*60*60)
gen  bedrenabo=1 if v1<v2
order bedrenabo v1 v2
replace bedrenabo=0 if v1==v2
replace bedrenabo=0 if v1<0
replace bedrenabo=0 if v1>v2
gen double newack1=ack[_n-1] if bedrenabo==1
format newack %tc
order Handling newack1 ack det tra
sort uniquenr det
replace ack=newack1 if newack1!=.
```

and my result is

```
    ack            det                     uniquenr newack 

02mar2015 10:30:19  27feb2015 17:03:25 1

09mar2015 11:56:44  07mar2015 22:05:52 2

16mar2015 09:59:51  09mar2015 11:08:36 2 09mar2015 11:56:44

16mar2015 09:59:51  09mar2015 11:08:36 2

16mar2015 09:59:51  09mar2015 11:08:36 2

16mar2015 09:59:51  09mar2015 11:08:36 2

24feb2015 15:03:00  21feb2015 10:23:00 3
```

The problem seems to arise because there are duplicates in the data and I use `[_n-1]`. The optimal solution would be to use a `replace` command which for all observations with the same `det` and `uniquenr` replaces all missing values with the known `newack` - if there is a `newack`. The command `bysort uniquenr det : replace nyack1 = newack1[_n-1] if missing(newack1)` gives different amounts of change for each time.

I am not yet familiar with `foreach` loops, but if that's the way, I am open to it.

Comment: The question is not very clear: you say you want to change det (det must be matched to the earliest possible following ack), but it seems you're changing ack. Also, did you get the data as it is, or was it in two separate lists initially? If the latter, adjusting the initial merge might be easier. Describing what ack and det stand for might also help to understand the question.

Comment: I agree with @Andrei. I read this about three times and just got more confused about what you're doing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please.

Comment: Hi @Andrei. I recieved the data as they are and due to other variables not mentioned in the example, I cannot simple remerge. The time-difference between ACK and DET must be as small as possible, and only ACK and DET with the same UNIQUENR can be combined.  ACK=Acknowledge, DET=Detection, both are datetimes.

Comment: @Nick, I am sorry that my question confuses you. How can I help you understand my question more clear? I appreciate good advise!

Comment: Suppose you have a set of some ack and det times for a given identifier, you have equal number of ack and det times, and there is no established pairing yet. Are you saying there is always a pairing then that you want to achieve? Are you further allowed to modify either ack or det times? If yes, what modifications are allowed?

Comment: Catch-22: If I understood the question, I could advise well on how to reframe it. I've already asked for MCVE. That is, we need a self-contained small example from data input through to what you want. No need for millisecond-based date-times; just use really simple "times" with small integer values that show the logic here.

Comment: @Andrei, precisely. There are exeptions in the dataset, where the correct DET and ACK timedifference is a negative value (as seen in my code I defined my dummy variable as values above zero.), I assume, I would loose these with a re-join. I am allowed to motify ACK, not DET, and ACK can be motified to be motified to any value of ACK within the same uniquenr.

Comment: But then the original data seems correct, no? Ack >= Det, so there are no negative differences. Moreover, even a stronger condition holds in your original example: min(Ack) >= max(Det) within each group...

Comment: @Andrei, in my original dataset there are examples of negative differencen and they are correct. The problem in the remaining parts of my dataset (and in the example above) are the mismatches where DET is matched not to the first possible ACK but to the second (see the ACK value for DET=09mar2015 in example1 and afterwards look at the ACK value for DET=07mar2015. ACK should have been 09mar2015 for them both) if you look clearly, it is easy to spot the problem :)

Comment: Yes min(Ack)>=max(Det), but it is not the smallest ACK that is applied for each DET.

Comment: New question: You suggest to correct row 3 but row 4 is exactly the same as row 3. Why not correct row 4 then as well?

Comment: @Andrei - reread my original question ;) The problem is that I have to correct row 3-6 but my code only applies for row 3 and I have no idea how to wirte a code including the rest of the rows. Are you able to write a code for that?

Comment: Ok, I am starting to understand the question, I think. So, within the same `uniquenr` you want to match to each `det` the smallest possible `ack` that is at least as large as that `det`. Is that it? Or do you simply want to match the smallest possible `ack`, no matter if it is smaller than the corresponding `det`?

Comment: @Andrei Yes exactely! The first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, ok, assuming that I understand the question, here is one possible solution.

Please note, that I've modified you original example to make it more general (otherwise a simple `egen` will do, but it seems to me that is not what you want).

```
// Input the data
// @Msh, generally it is helpful if you provide somthing like this with your Q.
clear
input str18 ackstr str18 detstr uniquenr
"02mar2015 10:30:19" "27feb2015 17:03:25" 1
"09mar2015 11:56:44" "07mar2015 22:05:52" 2
"16mar2015 09:59:51" "09mar2015 11:08:36" 2
"16mar2015 09:59:51" "09mar2015 11:08:36" 2
"16mar2015 09:59:51" "09mar2015 11:08:36" 2
"16mar2015 09:59:51" "09mar2015 11:08:36" 2
"24feb2015 15:03:00" "21feb2015 10:23:00" 3
end

gen double ack = clock(ackstr, "DMYhms")
gen double det = clock(detstr, "DMYhms")
format ack det %tc
drop *str

// I will modify the original data to make it more general
replace ack = tc(08mar2015 00:00:00) in 5

// Add row identifiers
gen id = _n

// Create all possible combinations of ack and det withing the same uniquenr
preserve
    keep uniquenr ack
    rename ack new=
    tempfile ack
    save `ack'
restore
joinby uniquenr using `ack'

// Drop ack that are smaller than det
drop if newack < det

// Match the smallest ack to a given det
ds newack id, not
collapse (min) newack (last) `r(varlist)', by(id)
```

You can also do it with a loop, e.g. in this manner:

```
// Add row numbers
gen id = _n

// Prepare newack
gen double newack = .
format newack %tc

// Ensure the data is sorted
sort uniquenr ack

// Compute block boundaries
gen row = _n
by uniquenr: gen min = row[1]
by uniquenr: gen max = row[_N]

// Compute new ack
forvalues i = 1/`c(N)' {
    forvalues j = `=min[`i']'/`=max[`i']' {
        if `=ack[`j']' >= `=det[`i']' {
            replace newack = ack[`j'] in `i'
            continue, break
        }
    }
}

// Revert the sorting
sort id
```

If you have a large dataset, it might make sense to rewrite the loop in mata, which should be faster.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and suggestion. It certainly does the job. However, as I mentioned before, my supervisors already denied using a re-joining solution (I proposed a solution very close to yours last week), because it does not take special exceptions into account . I will mark the question as answered, because you did, and if you can think of another way to solve the problem, please let me know :) :)

Comment: @Msh, I've added another solution. Btw, why is the supervisor against remerging? It leaves the rest of the dataset as is...

Comment: thank you! I have no idea, why he is against it. He says it is harder to proof-read the code, when a re-merge is used.